# Horizontal scrollbar for long Matjax equations in HTML

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, mathjax

I have the following MWE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>I want long equations to be scrollable individually</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <!-- Math support https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted -->
    <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
      },
      svg: {
        fontCache: 'global'
      }
    };
    </script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <style>
        .equation {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .equation__content, .equation__number {
            display: table-cell;
        }
        .equation__content {
            width: 90%;
        }
        .equation__number {
            text-align: right;
            font-family: serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <p>Here we have a small equation which works perfectly:
    
    <div class="equation">
        <equation class="equation__content">
            $$E=mc^2$$
        </equation>
            <div class="equation__number">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</div>
    </div>
    
    Now, the following is a very long equation:
    
    <div class="equation">
        <div class="equation__content">
            $$\frac{dF}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{d\xi}=\intop_{\mathbb{R}}f(\zeta)e^{-\zeta}\cos(w^{2}-\zeta)\ d\zeta+\frac{3x^{3}+(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E})\cdot\boldsymbol{B}}{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{E}}+8\pi\hbar+\log\cos\tan\sin\pi$$
        </div>
            <div class="equation__number">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</div>
    </div>
    
    which produces a "global horizontal scrollbar" for the <code>body</code> element. I would like to keep the <code>body</code> without scrollbar and add a small scrollbar only to long equaitons.
    </p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This produces a "global" scroll bar like this (you may have to reduce the width of your window):

[image]

I would like to get this instead:

[image]

By now I have tried with almost all the answers I found with Google with no success. For example with

```css
.equation__content {
    width: 90%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I avoid the global scroll bar but I don't get the local scroll bar. I have tried all the options for `overflow-x` inside `.equation__content` and none of them works.

Is it possible to do what I want? (I hope it is because Stack Overflow is using this for the code blocks, each have their own "local scrollbars" when needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways would be is to use `white-space:nowrap;` for your formulas:

```css
.equation-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.equation-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.equation-table-col {
  float: left; /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: lightpink;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="equation-table">
      <div class="equation-table-row">
        <div class="equation-table-col" align="center">Some Header</div>
        <div class="equation-table-col">Some Header 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="equation-table-row">
        <div class="equation-table-col">$$E=mc^2$$</div>
        <div class="equation-table-col text-center">(1)</div>
      </div>
      <div class="equation-table-row">
        <div class="equation-table-col">
          $$\frac{dF}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{d\xi}=\intop_{\mathbb{R}}f(\zeta)e^{-\zeta}\cos(w^{2}-\zeta)\
          d\zeta+\frac{3x^{3}+(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E})\cdot\boldsymbol{B}}{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{E}}+8\pi\hbar+\log\cos\tan\sin\pi$$
        </div>
        <div class="equation-table-col text-center">(2)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

[As mdn says about](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) `table-layout: fixed`:

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
> elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
> subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to adapt it to my needs but I don't get the results I am looking for. The table seems to have some fixed width despite it is set to `100%`, and does not change dynamically as I change the width of the browser window. It seems to be related to the width of the equation it contains.

Comment: @user171780 just add `table-layout: fixed`. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is almost doing what I want. I edited my question, I only need to center the equation number vertically and it is done. After this I can accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Finally I managed to do it using flex. I accepted your answer though.

Comment: @user171780 I centered text align. Thanks for accepting. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the way of doing what I want as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>I want long equations to be scrollable</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <!-- Math support https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted -->
    <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
      },
      svg: {
        fontCache: 'global'
      }
    };
    </script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <style>
        .numbered_equation_container {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .equation {
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        .equation_number {
            display: table-column;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <p>Here we have a small equation which works perfectly:
    
    <div class="numbered_equation_container">
         <div class="equation">
            $$E=mc^2$$
        </div>
        <div class="equation_number">(1)</div>
    </div>
    
    Now, the following is a very long equation:
    
    <div class="numbered_equation_container">
        <div class="equation">
            $$\frac{dF}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{d\xi}=\intop_{\mathbb{R}}f(\zeta)e^{-\zeta}\cos(w^{2}-\zeta)\
            d\zeta+\frac{3x^{3}+(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E})\cdot\boldsymbol{B}}{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{E}}+8\pi\hbar+\log\cos\tan\sin\pi$$
        </div>
        <div class="equation_number">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2)</div>
    </div>
    
    which produces a "global horizontal scrollbar" for the <code>body</code> element. I would like to keep the <code>body</code> without scrollbar and add a small scrollbar only to long equaitons.
    </p>
    
</body>
</html>
```